# How to know what javascript file manipulates codes like "javascript:void(0)"?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, breakpoints

I'm needing help to debug a code.
If we have a code like this one:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">My link</a>
```

How could I know what javascript file manipulates the click on this element?
I'm trying to search at the js available files, but I couldn't find what file manipulates the click. This process, to search manually, is very annoying and slow.

How could I know what js (the file, the line) manipulates codes like this one?

Comment: They are using `javascript:void(0)` to stop the link from going anywhere. It isn't anything that is user-defined in a js file

Comment: I dont think you can get that info with just this piece. You need to take into account the other relevant DOM elements as well